# Ball doesn't stop when it hit to a wall

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am very new to the unity.I am developing a game in 3D but if i drag a ball using touch and if that ball hit to a wall then the ball doesn't stop,rather it goes throw the wall and cross it.Sorry for my poor english but i really need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are going add a LOT more information. This is not clear at all. What is the technique you are using moving the ball? Force ? Transform Position? Which objects have rigidbody? Try to provide your code, scene, object properties in an image if you can. Other than that, people cannot magically guess what is in your scene or what is the problem.

Comment: I want to make a 3d game using unity which can be played in android mobile.In this game the ball will be moved by different block and finally it will be reached to a destination point but the problem is when the ball hit to a wall,it goes through the wall and doesn't stop.

I have used the Rigidbody in ball object(sphere) and it hits a wall(cube) which have used box collider but doesn't stop when it hits to a wall.I have used Transform Position force to move the Ball.

Answer (score 0):

Move your rigidbody like so:

```
Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;

yourRigidbody.MovePostition(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, Camera.main.nearClipPlane)));
```